# Subset columns in R with specific values

Tags: r

Given a large data frame e.g. df, with 500 columns and 100 rows, how do I just subset columns exceeding a specific threshold e.g. 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: Please do post a small example dataset and your expected result as your description is not very specific

Comment: How is a column exceeding the threshold? the mean of the column? all of the values being greater than 1? the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean subset columns that all of their values are greater than 1 you could do something like this (essentially you can also use the following according to any condition you might have. Just change the `if` condition):

**Example Data**

```
a <- data.frame(matrix(runif(90),ncol=3))

> a
           X1         X2         X3
1  0.33341130 0.09307143 0.51932506
2  0.78014395 0.30378432 0.67309736
3  0.19967771 0.30829771 0.60144888
4  0.77736355 0.42504910 0.23880491
5  0.60631868 0.55198423 0.29565519
6  0.24246456 0.57945721 0.17882712
7  0.10499677 0.48768998 0.54931955
8  0.92288335 0.29290491 0.72885160
9  0.85246128 0.87564673 0.60069170
10 0.39931205 0.29895856 0.83249469
11 0.33674259 0.85618041 0.62940935
12 0.27816980 0.51508938 0.76079354
13 0.19121182 0.27586235 0.21273823
14 0.66337625 0.18631150 0.67762964
15 0.00923405 0.84753915 0.08386400
16 0.33209371 0.54919903 0.49128825
17 0.97685675 0.25564765 0.56439142
18 0.26710042 0.75852884 0.88706946
19 0.32422355 0.58971620 0.84070049
20 0.73000898 0.09068726 0.92541277
21 0.80547283 0.93723241 0.31050230
22 0.28897215 0.80679092 0.06080124
23 0.32190269 0.12254342 0.42506740
24 0.52569405 0.68506407 0.68302356
25 0.31098388 0.66225007 0.08565480
26 0.67546897 0.08123716 0.58419470
27 0.29501987 0.17836528 0.79322116
28 0.20736102 0.81145297 0.44078101
29 0.75165829 0.51865202 0.36653840
30 0.63375066 0.03804626 0.69949846
```

**Solution**

Just a single `lapply` is enough. I use `0.05` as threshold here because it is easier to demonstrate how to use it according to my random data set. Change that to whatever you want in your dataset.

```
b <- do.call(cbind, (lapply(a, function(x) if(all(x>0.05)) return(x) )))
```

**Output**

```
> b
              X3
 [1,] 0.51932506
 [2,] 0.67309736
 [3,] 0.60144888
 [4,] 0.23880491
 [5,] 0.29565519
 [6,] 0.17882712
 [7,] 0.54931955
 [8,] 0.72885160
 [9,] 0.60069170
[10,] 0.83249469
[11,] 0.62940935
[12,] 0.76079354
[13,] 0.21273823
[14,] 0.67762964
[15,] 0.08386400
[16,] 0.49128825
[17,] 0.56439142
[18,] 0.88706946
[19,] 0.84070049
[20,] 0.92541277
[21,] 0.31050230
[22,] 0.06080124
[23,] 0.42506740
[24,] 0.68302356
[25,] 0.08565480
[26,] 0.58419470
[27,] 0.79322116
[28,] 0.44078101
[29,] 0.36653840
[30,] 0.69949846
```

Only column 3 confirmed the condition on this occasion so it was returned.

Answer (score 3):

Or another option (based on @LyzandeR's data).  Get the `colSums` of the logical condition (`a <= 0.05`) and negate it (`!`).  If there are `0` values for a particular column, this step converts to `TRUE`.  This can be used for selecting the columns.

```
a[,!colSums(a<=0.05), drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: Good one. Vectorised solution as well. It deserves to be the accepted answer.

Comment: @LyzandeR, akrun, just benchmarked both your solutions with a 1000x1000 dataframe (not so big but still gives a hint...) and, as akrun said, LyzandeR's solution is more efficient. Still, this is a good solution

Comment: Thank you both for comments and thanks @CathG for getting in the trouble of testing. It certainly added to my knowledge. Thanks. (I also still agree that this indeed is a nice solution)!