# select only columns containing values > 5 from a data frame

Tags: r, select

Pretty new to R, so this has been a struggle: I have a data frame imported from a csv. The first columns contains the row names (genes), the second column contains group assignment (if a gene is in group 1 or group 4 etc). The next 100 columns contain gene pathway measurements (range -20 to +20). I would like to select only the rows in group 1, and then only display columns for group 1 rows that contain at least 1 value greater than 10.

example data:

```
NAME    Group   path1   path2   path3   path4   path5
gene1   8   -19.1   -26.6   3.0 0.8 -5.1
gene2   1   -2.8    22.8    -1.2    20.8    -9.6
gene3   4   -5.4    -4.0    2.7 5.8 -6.8
gene4   1   -9.9    -24.6   7.3 -2.1    -18.9
gene5   2   -4.7    -9.4    -3.1    0.6 -10.1
gene6   1   14.0    -5.8    -1.6    -2.5    -18.7
gene7   5   -6.4    -3.8    2.0 -2.1    -8.6
gene8   1   -9.9    -4.8    5.2 2.0 -17.5
```

I have tried this approach but had trouble fitting it to my data
[Subset columns in R with specific values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214062/subset-columns-in-r-with-specific-values)

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape your data to ease your manipulation with `tidyr`  and  `dplyr`. It will put your colname in a column. Then filter on Group and value.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
  gather("Path", "value", -NAME, -Group) %>%
  filter(Group == 1, value > 10)
#>    NAME Group  Path value
#> 1 gene6     1 path1  14.0
#> 2 gene2     1 path2  22.8
#> 3 gene2     1 path4  20.8
```

If you want all rows `Group == 1` and all values from selected columns, just keep the colnames and subset your table

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
colname <- DT %>% 
  gather("Path", "value", -NAME, -Group) %>%
  filter(Group == 1, value > 10) %>%
  select(Path)

DT[DT$Group == 1, c("NAME", "Group", colname$Path)]
#>    NAME Group path1 path2 path4
#> 2 gene2     1  -2.8  22.8  20.8
#> 4 gene4     1  -9.9 -24.6  -2.1
#> 6 gene6     1  14.0  -5.8  -2.5
#> 8 gene8     1  -9.9  -4.8   2.0
```

Comment: this worked - i used all values from the selected columns (the second part of your solution). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Staying just within base R, and making use of the question you linked to we can do

```
## Data
df <- data.frame(NAME = c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4"),
                             Group = c(8,1,4,1),
                             path1 = c(-19.1, -2.8, -5.4, -9.9),
                             path2 = c(-26.6, 22.8, -4, -24.6))

drops <- c("NAME", "Group")
keeps <- names(df)[!names(df) %in% drops]

## Subset the data by the groups of interest first
df_1 <- df[df$Group == 1,]

## This next step is similar to your linked question, 
## it just uses `any` in place of `all`, and only on a subset of the columns

cbind(df_1[, drops], do.call(cbind, lapply(df_1[, keeps], function(x){ if(any(x >= 5)) return(x) }) ) )

## Or alternatively, 
df_1[, c(drops, do.call(c, sapply(keeps, function(x) if(any(df[, x] >= 5)) return(x)))) ]
```

which gives

```
   NAME Group path2
2 gene2     1  22.8
4 gene4     1 -24.6
```

Comment: I went with Titolondon second solution because it retained all of the information in the column. Thank you though for taking the effort to reply.

Comment: @user27206 I'm not sure I understand your comment - my solution retains all the information in the column too ? (Note I'm using a smallser subset of your data in my example)

Comment: This is great for package developers that for sustainability want to keep away from other dependencies (tidyverse is great, but changes VERY often ginormously). Thanks!